# Pandas loop through Excel sheets and append to df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to loop through an Excel sheet and append the data from multiple sheets into a data frame.

So far I have:

```
master_df = pd.DataFrame()
for sheet in target_sheets:
    df1 = file.parse(sheet, skiprows=4) 
    master_df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

But then when I call `master_df.head()` it returns `__`

The data on these sheets is in the same format and relate to each other.

So I would like to join them like this:

Sheet 1 contains:

```
A1
B1
C1
```

Sheet 2 contains:

```
A2
B2
C2
```

Sheet 3:

```
A3
B3
C3
```

End result:

```
A1
B1
C1
A2
B2
C2
A3
B3
C3
```

Is my logic correct or how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet) for sheet in ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3']], axis=1)
```

For example, will yield:

```
   A1  B1  C1  A2  B2  C2  A3  B3  C3
0   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   4   5   6   4   5   6
2   7   8   9   7   8   9   7   8   9
```

Answer (score 9):

**Below code will work even if you don't know the exact sheet_names** in the excel file. You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('myexcel.xls')

out_df = pd.DataFrame()

for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel('myexcel.xls', sheet_name=sheet)
    out_df.append(df)  ## This will append rows of one dataframe to another(just like your expected output)

print(out_df)

## out_df will have data from all the sheets
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is useful, but I do know the sheet names I want in this instance.

Comment: Sure. I just gave you a more general solution which does not involve any hardcoding of sheet-names.

Answer (score 0):

The output desired in the question is obtained by setting axis=0.

```py
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(io="projects.xlsx", sheet_name=sheet) for sheet in ['JournalArticles','Proposals','Books']], axis=0)
df2
```